# Searching messages for content contained in "Message Source"?

Tags: thunderbird, thunderbird-addon

Anyone know a way to search messages for content contained within the Message Source of messages, using built-in methods or third-party extensions?

When I search for content contained within the Message Source of messages, a Body search will not find those messages. Here is the list of criteria choices available when I perform a search. I'm not sure if "Customize" would be useful for what I'm attempting. This is Thunderbird 102.12.0 (64-bit) on Win10x64:

Screenshot:

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

If you're willing to keep Thunderbird files in folders *ImapMail* and *Mail* in plain text, rather than encrypted, they're easily indexed by almost any search utility. Below, [DocFetcher](https://docfetcher.sourceforge.net/en/index.html) is shown searching for *meganet* in local email files, and the term is found in the message header.

[image: DocFetcher Indexing]

- To enable global search, i.e., turn off encryption of local files,

  - Open *Thunderbird* preferences.
  - In the *Search* box, enter *index*.
  - Check *Enable Global Search and Indexer*.
- *In the search indexing utility*, set WDSEML file type to be fully searched.
- *In the search indexing utility*, build indexes for /ImapMail andMail folders.

Messages will be stored in WDSEML file format (HTML). Of course, that means the messages are easily readable by anyone with access to the PC, unless that partition is encrypted.

Comment: Hi @DrMoishe Pippik - thanks for your DocFetcher suggestion but I'm looking for an inline solution, in other words, from within Thunderbird.  I use the Thunderbird Message Search window a lot so it would have to be a solution that works from within there.